# I recently started learning SQL & I'm having a problem trying to perform very basic window Functions on mySQL. I have no idea why

Tags: sql, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
     emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
     first_name VARCHAR(15),
     last_name VARCHAR(15),
     birth_date DATE,
     sex VARCHAR(2),
     salary INT,
     supervisor_id INT,
     branch_id INT
);
```

I populated the table with a bunch of employees..

```
select *, avg(salary) over() from mysql.employee;
```

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() from mysql.employee' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your MySQL database version doesn't support `avg` function in its analytic form. Which version do you use? Because, a quick test shows that in version

- 8.0 query works as expected
- 5.7 (and lower) query raises error you got

Illustration:

[image]

Comment: i use a 8.0 version

Comment: mySQL underlines the brackets after the over in red, it does not underline the avg function in red

Comment: Have a look at image I posted; it shows that - in version 8.0 - it *works*.

Comment: i just checked my mysql commandline and its a 5.7, my workbench is however an 8.0 Youre right, i guess thats the reason im having a problem performing that query

Comment: Righ; just as I told you.

Comment: 5.7:  `select *, ( SELECT avg(salary) FROM mysql.employee ) AS 'avg' from mysql.employee;`  Create your own `DATABASE`, do not use `mysql`; it is for system information.